# SQL - defragmenting an index on a compressed table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, defragmentation

We have a database with 2 tables, one with hundreds of millions of rows (row size<1KB), another 14 million rows. Compression enabled on both. 
Database size was ~66GB. Everything worked fine.

Indexes were 75% fragmented. Coworker started REBUILD on both tables. It's been running for 4.5 hours now. The MDF is almost 150GB and LDF about 13GB and it keeps growing. We're about to run out of space.

What should we do? Wait for it to finish? Cancel query? Reboot SQL? Reboot server?

Comment: Index REBUILD is fully logged, so that LDF will get pretty large, but not sure how large it gets compared to the index size.

Comment: Did you turn on minimal logging by any chance (bulk logged)?  When rebuilding an index, SQL server will create a second index along side the first one (and require the file space for both) before removing the old one.  What size was the index before you rebuilt?

Comment: @GoatCO Funny, LDF was just 13GB, we were worried about MDF, which became 170GB by the time if finished. Thanks.

Comment: @Twelfth no we don't use bulk logging. I'll check on the size of the index after rebuild, not sure what it was before. It was the clustered index on both tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The process completed 7 hours into it, after consuming about 170GB for MDF file.

So the answer is:

1. Have plenty of disk space, close to what uncompressed data would be, or at least about 3x compressed;
2. Be prepared to increase disk space as needed, have IT around for it (either on a VM server or with a hot-swap physical box);
3. Always do one table at a time;
4. Be ready to wait a long time.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I didn't expect the 'uncompressed' file size to factor in here, I'll have to remember it's the uncompressed size that the new index file will need.  TY for sharing a solution